# Laravel - What steps should one take to make a Laravel app ready for production mode

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, development-environment, environment, production-environment

The scenario is I have developed a Laravel app in my localhost. Everything works fine. Now I need to make it go online. I  am just trying to figure out what steps (configuration , security etc.) should I take before I make it go online.

I am listing a few steps:

1) Change in `.env` file to make the environment point to production mode using `APP_ENV=production`.

2)  Avoide showing errors directly in pages as that would expose the innards of the app. Enable error logging instead.

3) Use caching for faster user experience
4) building a nice 404, not found page

What else should I undertake to turn the app from development mode into production mode ?

Answer (score 94):

1. Apply changes to `.env` file:

   - `APP_ENV=production`
   - `APP_DEBUG=false`
2. Make sure that you are optimizing Composer's class autoloader map ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md)):

   - `composer dump-autoload --optimize`
   - or along install: `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`
   - or during update: `composer update --optimize-autoloader`
3. Optimizing Configuration Loading:

   - `php artisan config:cache`
4. Discover and cache the application's events and listeners:

   - `php artisan event:cache`
5. Optimizing Route registration:

   - `php artisan route:cache`
6. Compile all of the application's Blade templates:

   - `php artisan view:cache`
7. Cache the framework bootstrap files:

   - `php artisan optimize`
8. (Optional) Asset Bundling:

   - Using Vite Laravel Plugin ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/vite)): `npm run build`
   - Using Laravel Mix ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix)): `npm run production`
9. (Optional) Generate the encryption keys Laravel Passport needs ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#deploying-passport)):

   - `php artisan passport:keys`
10. (Optional) Start Laravel task scheduler by adding the following Cron entry ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#introduction)):

    - `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
11. (Optional) Install, config and start the Supervisor ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#supervisor-configuration)):
12. (Optional) Create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk)):

    - `php artisan storage:link`

---

- Laravel deployment docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment
- Digital Ocean's tutorial: [How to Install and Configure Laravel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: `php artisan optimize` hasn't been needed since Laravel 5.5

Comment: @AmirAsyraf currently optimize is as same as calling `config:cache` and `route:cache`, however I preferred to mention it due to probable behavior changes in the future.

Comment: @HafezDivandari Is there a reason that compiling assets with `npm run` is optional? Isn't it required?

Comment: @HashimAziz the app may don't have any front-end assets to compile, on the other hand there is no need to re-compile assets on the deployment if you haven't injected any [env variables](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#environment-variables)

Comment: @Hafez thanks. Really useful. I had to use ```npm run build``` instead of ```npm run production```

Answer (score 4):

There are some steps you can check

1. Install LEMP or LAMP stack.
2. You can check/add PHP and Dependencies for Laravel
3. Test Your Site’s Functionality
4. Optimize Image Size
5. Google Analytics & SEO addition
6. Check w3 validation
7. Page speed optimization

Comment: except 5 and possibly 7, all other points are to supposed to be tested  in localhost, right ?

Answer (score 1):

**configuration**

- set app_debug to false
- make sure you are setting proper folder permissions

**Security**

- use ssl certificate -> you can do configuration with nginx or apache for the same
- redirect all requests to https after setting up ssl
- set very strong database password
- if your app has api's then use api throttling

Comment: what do you mean use api throttling?

Comment: @FernandoTorres please refer this link - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#attaching-rate-limiters-to-routes