# New CSS file is empty/404 not found in chrome inspector after hosted. It works fine at local but not in website

Tags: html, css, laravel

I just made a new CSS file and named it `new-style.css` in my Laravel project. The path is `public/assets/css`. It's just a short line of CSS. I've tested it locally and it works fine. The view of the project was changed. But when I test it on product server, it has no change at all. New CSS file exists but there's no change in the view of my project. I checked in file manager of cPanel, that new CSS file already exists and is updated. Please look at the pictures below for more details.

[When I inspect the website of my project, that new-style.css file is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWIAW.jpg)

[When I look at Network tab in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5frnQ.jpg)

[Even though the file exists in cPanel's file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ0dW.jpg)

And this is the code of my new CSS file :

```
#order-table {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.glass-card {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.40 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 17.5px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 17.5px );
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 );
}
```

What's wrong whit this? I've searched by myself but still not found the answer of my problem. I hope i'll find it here. Your help is very valuable for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After deploying your Laravel project into deployement try first running `npm run prod`.

Then run the following commands:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`

I find this checklist is helpful when deploying Laravel projects: [Laravel - What steps should one take to make a Laravel app ready for production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663762/laravel-what-steps-should-one-take-to-make-a-laravel-app-ready-for-production)