# Laravel - speed can it be improved to under 70ms?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-8, response

I were programming for more than 15+ years, and yesterday I was thinking about starting to use Laravel, but when I installed it (fresh installation), their default "welcome" route was using **140ms** as response time from server (just response from server, not loading anything else from html). So 1 route, no database, anything.

And I used to create my own framework which had response time **47ms** with connecting to database, executing few queries and working with templates (created my own templating system). Both tested on same server.

And because of that I am a bit worried about the response time, will it work with a lot of users on website?
I am trying to use laravel just because I see a lot of jobs opportunity that are asking for laravel developers.

Comment: Are you testing in dev or [production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664416/231316)?

Comment: Testing in production and with debug set to false

Comment: All frameworks are going to have some kind of overhead wr/t response time, memory usage, etc.; that's the price of using them. But what you lose in those areas, you gain in others, like development time, convenience, customizability and extensions, etc. I've worked with Laravel since version 4.2, and as long as you're not doing anything crazy, those have never been major issues in production. Would a pure PHP project be faster? You bet. Would I go back? Not likely.

Comment: Thank you for your information on experience with laravel, well i used to create things from scratch always, i loved it.. But finding a job with it isn't really something that companies are searching.. I will give it a try in any way.. But was curious can it be executed faster, as i like speed..

Comment: No problem! And I hear ya; nowadays companies looking for experience in `Language X` often also include (not necessarily _require_ though) experience in `Framework Y`. PHP knowledge should translate well to Laravel, but there are definitely some "Laravel-isms" to get used to. Unfortunately, I've never really dug into performance increases, as it neither my area of expertise nor a necessity (i.e. it's always been "fast enough" for me, unless I was doing something dumb like N+1 queries, etc.), so I can't say if it _can_ be improved... Anyway, best of luck, and hope you enjoy Laravel 

Comment: So in a little it's gonna include bonus if know all frameworks :D . I used to program in C++ from begin, and still using it, so after i switched to php it was easy to hardcode from scratch everything, but using laravel will be somethign different, i need to learn their code to start using it, i hope i will succeed in it. But good side is i recently bough phpstorm i think it will help me alot with this task..

Comment: Yeah, for sure! Good companies/IT recruiters should know that experience in _any_ language can translate to others; one job I worked was as a Ruby/Rails developer, and I was hired due to my PHP/Laravel experience. Those are special cases, as those frameworks were developed based on each other (I forget the order though), but the point still stands. And yeah, PHPStorm is a great IDE option, although I haven't worked with it directly. VSCode (or similar) can be good with extensions too, but it's a personal preference mostly 